# Doesn't OneToOneField of Django refer another table's id field?

Tags: python, django

I thought `models.OneToOneField`, in this case group field, refers `Group` table's id field.
But, through my `views.py`, that Group's `id == 6` but Group_Cover's `group_id == 3` happens if I don't upload image when Group's `id == 2, 3 and 4`.

Sorry, my English is strange. 
In short, I thought `Django` set 6 in Group_Cover's group_id when Group's id is 6.

models.py

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Group(models.Model):

    #group_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        db_table = traceback.extract_stack()[-2][2].lower()


@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Group_Cover(models.Model):

    group = models.OneToOneField(Group, primary_key=True)
    group_cover = models.ImageField(upload_to="static/image/group/")

    class Meta:
        db_table = traceback.extract_stack()[-2][2].lower()
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='/')
def group_register(request):

    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    from myapp.forms import GroupRegister
    from myapp.forms import GroupCover
    formset = GroupRegister
    formcover = GroupCover

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = formset(request.POST)
        cover = formcover(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            from myapp.models import Group
            new_group = Group()
            new_group.group_name = form.cleaned_data['group_name']
            new_group.save()

            from myapp.models import Group_Cover
            new_cover = Group_Cover()
            new_cover.group_cover = request.FILES['group_cover']
            new_cover.save()

            return redirect('/myapp/group_page/{}'.format(new_group.id))

    else:
        form = formset()
        cover = formcover()

    view = { 
        'form': form,
        'cover': cover,
    }
    template = 'myapp/group/group_register.html'
    return render(request, template, view)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to assign the `Group` instance to the `Group_Cover` one. More or less so:

```
   if form.is_valid():
        from myapp.models import Group
        new_group = Group()
        new_group.group_name = form.cleaned_data['group_name']
        new_group.save()

        from myapp.models import Group_Cover
        new_cover = Group_Cover()
        new_cover.group_cover = request.FILES['group_cover']

        new_cover.group = new_group # This line assigns it

        new_cover.save()
```

Comment: Thank you, Vladir Parrado Cruz. I didn't know that. I try now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You have not specified the group while initializing `Group_Cover`.

Instead of following code:

```
new_cover = Group_Cover()
```

Use the following:

```
new_cover = Group_Cover(group=new_group)
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you, Sudip Kafle.

Answer (score 2):

```
new_cover = Group_Cover(group=new_group)
new_cover.group_cover = request.FILES['group_cover']
new_cover.save()
```

Need to tell Django what group you are refering to (see `group=new_group`)